# Command line to run the Ant task with hyphen in the task name

Tags: ant

The task name starts with a hyphen "-".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="proj">
    <target name="-task1">
        <echo>Done!</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

How can I specify this task when running ant script from command line? This would not work:

```
ant -task1 -f test.xml
```

Comment: Why do you need to start task name with `-`?

Comment: I am building Android project. And for some reason the task names looks like "-pre-build".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Enclose the task name in quotes.

```
ant "-task1" -f test.xml
```

Update:
From [Ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html)

```
Targets beginning with a hyphen such as "-restart" are valid,
and can be used to name targets that should not be called directly
from the command line.
For Ants main class every option starting with hyphen is an option for Ant itself
and not a target. For that reason calling these target from command line is not
possible. On the other hand IDEs usually don't use Ants main class as entry 
point and calling them from the IDE is usually possible.
```

Comment: This would not work, at least on Windows. The error messages is: Unknown argument: -task1

Comment: Sorry this wasn't helpful, was tested on a linux box.

Comment: Wonder if it even possible. May be Android team used "-" to make some tasks invisible from outside.

Comment: Nope.  The quotes are the purview of the shell, which will make that into [ant] [-task1] when executing the command, which is the same problem.  If quoted rule name works for you, then unquoted also works for you.

Comment: Good information about why some tasks are started with -, but I think the correct answer is the one provided by David W.  I'm not sure why enclosing it in quotes worked - I would think that would not work even under UNIX.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on CentOS with Ant 1.9.2.  Ant just treated the target with dash as an option.

Comment: See Heefan's answer.

Answer (score 13):

Some people start internal targets with dashes just to make sure users cannot run them from the command line. In fact, I make it a standard practice to have all internal targets start with `-` just for this reason.

You can try the old double-dash trick. I don't have Ant installed on my current system, so I can't test it. Double dashes is a common Unix trick that most commands use to help end parameters when you have files and stuff that start with a dash. By the way, the tasks should be the last thing on your command line:

```
$ ant -f test.xml -- -task1
```

Worse comes to worse, you can simply define another target in your `build.xml` file that depends upon this target with the dash in it:

```
<task name="sneaky"
    depends="-task1"/>
```

Then you should be able to call `sneaky`:

```
$ant -f test.xml sneaky
```

Comment: Sadly the double-dash trick doesn't seem to work. I tested it on Windows and Linux and just get: `Unknown argument: --`

Comment: @MartinMcNulty Doesn't work for me on CentOS with Ant 1.9.2 neither.  Ant just treated the target with dash as an option.

Comment: Yes, the double dash is not processed by the shell but given to the called command like any other argument. If `ant` doesn't handle that in a particular way, it's not going to help.

Answer (score 6):

From the [ANT target doc](https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html)

> Targets beginning with a hyphen such as "-restart" are valid, and can be used to name targets that should not be called directly from the command line. 
>   For Ants main class every option starting with hyphen is an option for Ant itself and not a target. For that reason calling these target from command line is not possible.

So, user cannot call the target with hyphen from commandline.

Tested on Windows Platform on 21 April 2016.

Comment: Too bad the only answer with actually correct information is at the bottom of the list.